# How to return different types from a single function

Tags: c, function, return, void-pointers

I have the following c code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *func(int a) { 
    if (a==3) {
        int a_int = 5;
        int *ptr_int = &a_int;
        return (void *)ptr_int;
    } 
    else if (a==4) {
        char a_char = 'b';
        char *ptr_char = &a_char;
        return (void *)ptr_char;
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "return value is NULL");
        return NULL;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int *ptr_int = (int *)func(3);
    char *ptr_char = (char *)func(4);
    fprintf(stdout, "int value = %d\n", *ptr_int);
    fprintf(stdout, "char value = %c\n", *ptr_char);
    return 0; 
}
```

But when I use gcc to test this code, I have the following results :

> ```
> int value = 98
> char value = �
> root@coupure:/home/bohao/Desktop/test1375# gcc test.c -o test
> root@coupure:/home/bohao/Desktop/test1375# ./test 
> int value = 98
> char value = 
> root@coupure:/home/bohao/Desktop/test1375# gcc test.c -o test
> root@coupure:/home/bohao/Desktop/test1375# ./test 
> int value = 98
> char value = 
> root@coupure:/home/bohao/Desktop/test1375# gcc test.c -o test
> root@coupure:/home/bohao/Desktop/test1375# ./test 
> int value = 98
> char value = 
> root@coupure:/home/bohao/Desktop/test1375# gcc test.c -o test
> root@coupure:/home/bohao/Desktop/test1375# ./test 
> int value = 98
> char value = 
> root@coupure:/home/bohao/Desktop/test1375# gcc test.c -o test
> root@coupure:/home/bohao/Desktop/test1375# ./test 
> int value = 98
> char value = g
> root@coupure:/home/bohao/Desktop/test1375# gcc test.c -o test
> root@coupure:/home/bohao/Desktop/test1375# ./test 
> int value = 98
> char value = 
> root@coupure:/home/bohao/Desktop/test1375# gcc test.c -o test
> root@coupure:/home/bohao/Desktop/test1375# ./test 
> int value = 98
> char value = !
> ```

Why do I have the **98** for ptr_int and the **random value** of ptr_char ? 
What I want is to have **a general function** who can return different types of values instead of using two functions. Is that possible ? If so, how to do it ?

Comment: You cannot return a stack allocated pointer (local scoped) from a function....

Comment: No,  you can't return multiple types.

Comment: @GiladNaaman So it is not possible to make a general function ?

Comment: IMO you should rethink your design.

Comment: Return a dynamically-allocated variant type.  That's it, really.

Comment: Automatic variables do not persist after a function returns.  They're allocated on the stack.  This is very, very basic C.

Comment: @MartinJames, returning by value or by an output parameter may be better if the different members of the variant are small enough...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem as I see it, you're trying to `return` the address of a local variable from a function (scope) and trying to access the returned memory from the caller. In the caller, the memory is *invalid* and any usage will lead to  [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Solution: You need to use dynamic memory allocation for the pointer (`malloc()`/ `calloc()`) which you want to `return` from the function. This will overcome the issue here, as the lifetime of the dynamically allocated memory is untill `free()`-d manually or till program termination, whichever is earlier.

Having said that, this approach is not a good one. If all you want to return one of multiple types, go for a `struct` containing members for all types and use a flag to mark the type. Fill the corresponding member variable, set the flag and `return` the structure variable.

For better, you can actually use an `union` as a member of the structure, as you only need *one type at a time*. For a working code, please refer to [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37434038/2173917) by **@pmg**.

Comment: Since you only want one type at a time, I'd recommend a tagged union instead of just a struct.

Comment: @BohaoLI See PMG sir's answer, it should suffice for you. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh He apparently did what you said :) I already noticed it.

Answer (score 5):

You can return (a struct containing) an union

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

union members {
    int *intp;
    char *charp;
    double doublev;
};
struct group {
    int lastunionmember;
    union members x;
};

struct group f1(void) {
    struct group r = {0};
    int choice = rand() % 3;

    if (choice == 0) {
        r.x.intp = malloc(sizeof (int)); // remember to free(intp) at some time
        *r.x.intp = 42;
        r.lastunionmember = 1;
    }
    if (choice == 1) {
        r.x.charp = malloc(42); // remember to free(charp) at some time
        strcpy(r.x.charp, "forty two");
        r.lastunionmember = 2;
    }
    if (choice == 2) {
        r.x.doublev = 3.14159;
        r.lastunionmember = 3;
    }
    return r;
}

int main(void) {
    struct group x;
    srand(time(0));
    for (int k = 0; k < 20; k++) {
        x = f1();
        switch (x.lastunionmember) {
            default: printf("invalid value\n"); break;
            case 1: printf("int value is %d\n", *x.x.intp); break;
            case 2: printf("string is \"%s\"\n", x.x.charp); break;
            case 3: printf("double value is %f\n", x.x.doublev); break;
        }
    }
}
```

See the [code running at ideone](https://ideone.com/PnOq9f).

Comment: Why not simply avoid pointers inside union and allocate a union type pointer? `union members *my_var = malloc(sizeof(union members));`

Comment: That's a possibility @LPs, but it doesn't avoid allocating space for a string.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are returning the address of a local scoped variable. You have to use dynamic allocation to do what you want to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *func(int a)
{
    void *retVal = NULL;

    if (a==3)
    {
        retVal = malloc(sizeof(int));
        if (retVal != NULL)
        {
            *((int *)(retVal)) = 5;
        }
    }
    else if (a==4)
    {
        retVal = malloc(sizeof(int));
        if (retVal != NULL)
        {
            *((char *)(retVal)) = 'b';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "return value is NULL");
    }

    return retVal;
}

int main ()
{
    int *ptr_int = func(3);
    char *ptr_char = func(4);

    fprintf(stdout, "int value = %d\n", *ptr_int);
    fprintf(stdout, "char value = %c\n", *ptr_char);

    free(ptr_int);
    free(ptr_char);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the values that you return the pointers to are of *local scope*. This means that when the function returns the `a_char` and `a_int` variables effectively no longer exist, thus references to them (the pointers) are invalid.

The reason that you see the random output is because the memory that *was* used by those variables is now being used by something else.

You could either declare these variables at a wider scope (i.e. file scope or program scope) or use dynamic memory allocation.

This example uses file scope variables:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int a_int = 5;
static char a_char = 'b'

void *func(int a) { 
    if (a==3) {
        return (void *)&a_int;
    } 
    else if (a==4) {
        return (void *)&a_char;
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "return value is NULL");
        return NULL;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int *ptr_int = (int *)func(3);
    char *ptr_char = (char *)func(4);
    fprintf(stdout, "int value = %d\n", *ptr_int);
    fprintf(stdout, "char value = %c\n", *ptr_char);
    return 0; 
}
```

In this specific case you could also just return strings (which would be thread-safe):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * func(int a) {
    if (a == 3) {
        return "5";
    } else if (a == 4) {
        return "b";
    } else {
        return "Return value is nothing";
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    fprintf(stdout, func(3));
    fprintf(stdout, func(4));
    fprintf(stdout, func(15));
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I want to have as less static variables as possible cause static variable will bring thread-safe problems later.

Comment: If you do not wish to use static variables, then dynamic memory allocation is the method to use. However, ideally I would rethink a design that requires a function to return two different types. Take your code as an example, it prints both of the outputs regardless of type; meaning the function could return just `chars` one being the *character* `'5'` and the other `'b'`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a function that return two (or more) values, you have two possibilities:

1- Make the function `void` and return the values as parameters by reference &

2- Declare a struct (or class) that groups the values and make the function return a value of this struct.

Comment: But, if I make a function void, I would not be able to return pointers I think, right ?

Comment: You cannot return a pointer to a local variable in anyway. But if you allocate the pointer properly, you can return a pointer by reference. Just assign it to the parameter.