# c/c++ | int * excepted, int given (returning a pointer??)

Tags: c++, c, arrays, function-calls

So I am making a program to find the max possible substraction. If n is, f.e 9284, the minimum number which can be made with the digits of 9284 is 2489 and the maximum one is 9842. the function max_substraction returns 9842 - 2489 as output.

The problem is that whenever I run the program and type a number, the program crashes. I did try to debug and I was told that the function "to_digits" was excepting int * but int given which is really strange. Ain't I returning a pointer? ...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int valid(int);
int length(int);
int to_digits(int);
int to_num(int *, int);
void sort_digits(int *, int);
int max_substraction(int *, int);

int i,j;

int main()
{
    int num;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if(!valid(num))
    {
        printf("Invalid!\n");
    }
    else {

        printf("%d", max_substraction(to_digits(num), length(num)));
    }
    return 0;
}

int length(int num){

    int cpy_of_num = num, len = 0;
    do {
        cpy_of_num /= 10;
        len++;
    } while(cpy_of_num != 0);

    return len;
}

int valid(int num){
    int len = length(num);
    if(len<2 || len>9){
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
int to_digits(int num){
    int len = length(num), cpy_of_num = num;
    int digits[len];
    for(i=len-1; i>=0; i--){
        digits[i] = cpy_of_num % 10;
        cpy_of_num /= 10;
    }
    return *digits;
}
int to_num(int *digits, int len){
    int new_num = 0, mult = 1;
    for(i=len-1; i>=0; i--){
        new_num += digits[i]*mult;
        mult *= 10;
    }
    return new_num;
}
void sort_digits(int *digits, int len){
    for(i=1;i<len;i++){
        for(j=0;j<len-1;j++){
            if(digits[j] > digits[j+1]){
                int temp = digits[j];
                digits[j] = digits[j+1];
                digits[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
int max_substraction(int *digits, int len){
    sort_digits(digits, len);
    int max_num_digits[10], min_num_digits[10];
    for(i=0; i<len; i++){
        min_num_digits[i] = digits[i];
        max_num_digits[i] = digits[len-i-1];
    }
    int min_num = to_num(min_num_digits, len);
    int max_num = to_num(max_num_digits, len);

    return max_num - min_num;
}
```

Comment: What's the error and at which line?

Comment: The return statement of the "to_digits" function?

Comment: There is nothing as "C/C++" please choose one language and specify what you are compiling as.

Comment: This is almost a mix of both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the function call

```
  max_substraction(to_digits(num), length(num))
```

as per the signature,

```
int max_substraction(int *digits, int len)
```

the first param should be a `int *`, but `to_digits()` returns you an `int`!!

Then, a return statement like

```
  return *digits;
```

returns you an `int` value, not a pointer.

That said, even if you tried, in it's current form, `digits` array cannot be returned from `to_digits()`, as it is local to the function. You need to have static storage if you want to return the *array*. Now, since by definition, VLAs cannot have static storage, you may want to use memory allocator functions, like `malloc()` and family.

Comment: The question is why doesn't to_digits(num) return int *

Comment: @Caitiff just elaborated on that part.

Comment: THANK YOU OMFG I FIXED IT! haha

Comment: I fixed the declaration

Comment: well that was something i could notice by myself, sry for the stupid question

Comment: Yes Caitiff, and now fix the storage problem or you would still be returning a local variable which does not exist anymore after the return...another crash.

Comment: well I wrote 80 lines of code without testing it a lot. should have looked harder for my problem instead of going here, i admit that. anyways thanks for the help

Comment: @Caitiff *it works* doesn't mean it is correct. The problem is not just with the return type. There is a problem that you are returning an array which is out of scope.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I thought I made it clear in my answer itself...is it not? How I can clarify? Alternate wordings?

Comment: @SouravGhosh No, I am not saying anything about your answer. OP is jumping to conclusion that his problem his fixed by changing the declaration of `to_digits`. I was replying to his comment.

Comment: Um... I also fixed that as well

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I understand you're not pointing to my answer, just asking opinion about possible improvements, that's all. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Caitiff Because that is Undefined Behavior. There is no telling what would happen when UB is encountered. It might even given something similar to what you expect. But there is no point in discussing that. It might work here. In some other case it might not work (I can create a case where it will most definitely create issues).

Comment: Please do so. i would like to learn after all. give me such a case

Comment: Of course if you aren't careful, shit can happen but that doesn't mean it isnt correct

Comment: I suggest you create another case where you ask why returning a local array is not safe and I can answer that with examples. Better yet, just search on SO. The exact question must already have been asked.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya right indeed. -->Caitiff [here's one if you're interested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37433599/2173917)

Comment: but I am passing the array. In int main I am directly passing it to max substraction as a param. I am not using its values there

Comment: the function substraction itself calls the function to sort these digits

Answer (score 0):

Your function to_digits has a return type declared as int, while it in fact tries to return an int*.
In it's current form the array will cease to exist when the function ends, so a different way of memory allocation is required in order to use the array outside the function to_digits.

Comment: yeah my bad. I fixed the declaration. int* to_digits(int);